# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'IFCS.Entity' is less accessible than method 'IFCS.EntityOverviewPanel.setEntity(IFCS.Entity)'?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi there I got a problem with my application.

I created a new `UserControl` called `EntityOverviewPanel` to show information about another class `Entity` visually.
In order to create an instance of this UserControl I would like to pass an instance of `Entity` in order to initialize the panel with all data.

```
public partial class EntityOverviewPanel : UserControl
{
    private Entity entity;

    public EntityOverviewPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void setEntity(Entity e)
    {
        entity = e;
        updatePanel();
    }

    private void updatePanel()
    {
        //update panel
    }
}
```

If I try to execute this I get the error mentioned in the title:
`Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'IFCS.Entity' is less accessible than method 'IFCS.EntityOverviewPanel.setEntity(IFCS.Entity)'`

My Entity looks like this (only a part of the class because of its size^^)

```
class Entity
{
    public enum Gender
    {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }

    private int id;
    private Gender gender;
    private string surname, forename;
    private Group group;
    private Organisation organisation;
    private Station station;
    private string uid;

    public Entity(string surname, Gender gender, Group group, Role role, string forename = "")
    {
         //code
    }

    //more code
}
```

I read about changing `class Entity` to `public class Entity` would fix this problem but instead of doing that it just creates a whole bunch of new errors relating to other uses of `Entity` (with the same error message like in the title).

Any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes - either you need to make `Entity` public, or your `setEntity` method (which sounds like you're writing Java rather than C#) internal. Changing `EntityOverviewPanel` to be internal would fix it too, IIRC.

Fundamentally you *can't* have a public method in a public class with a parameter or return type which is internal. It doesn't make any sense to do so.

If making `Entity` public causes further problems, that's probably just because you need to do the same thing with other types. You really need to work out whether you *do* want `Entity` and its associated types to be public or not. If you don't want it to be public, why do you want `setEntity` to be public?

Comment: thanks Jon for you answer.
I'm sorry for not writing my code as any conventions wants it to look like but I do it by habit (did java and other languages in the past so I mix the conventions a bit sometimes).
I think it works now but I have to have a closer look to this topic because I don't really understand why this solution works^^
Do you know any good tutorials on this topic by any chance?

Comment: @Skadier: Not really - it's a pretty trivial topic. What would it *mean* to expose a public method without the parameter types being accessible? How could you call it, without even knowing if the type is a class or a struct? You couldn't even pass in `null`! Just think about *why* it doesn't make sense, and that should be able to guide you in future.